# How to calculate volume of revolution between a curve and a line

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I am currently trying to solve this problem:

> The area bounded between $y = x^2$ and $y = 4$ is rotated about the $y$-axis to form a solid. Find the volume generated.

So far, I have only learnt the $\int \pi x^2 dy$ for calculating a solid that is rotated around the y-axis. However, I am having trouble solving this question.

Can someone please help and guide me through on how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tried? Where is the difficulty? Have you done *any* problem of computing a volume of revolution?

Comment: @uniquesolution I have tried those simple problems on volume of revolution. However, I do not know how to calculate the volume between a curve and a line...

Comment: @uniquesolution I have tried the problem and got 2pi which was not the answer. The answer was 8pi...